# Handling Events QuickBooks Web Connector (PHP Soap Server)

Tags: php, soap, web, quickbooks, connector

Is it possible to subscribe to and query events using DataEventSubscriptionAddRq and DataEventSubscriptionQuery from a PHP Soap Server responding to QB Web Connector?  Based on my searches I believe it is not possible, but I hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use the `DataEventSubscription` functionality via the QuickBooks Web Connector.

Comment: Thanks, Keith.  I wanted to use it to detect (especially) merges and deletes on the QB side.  We just discovered ListDeletedQuery yesterday after quite a long time of using web connector, so at least we can know that a merge or delete has happened.  Is there anything else we have missed that we could be using to specifically detect merges (and know the ListIDs and other data involved in the merge) in QB using Web Connector?

Comment: ListDeletedQuery will return a deleted customer when two customers are merged. Outside of that, I'm not aware of any other way to detect the merge.